# How to download attachments from lotus notes using vb script

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vbscript

I have a code which downloads the attachment from the lotus notes. The problem is that each time it runs it downloads all the attachment. How can I give the condition not to download the  previously downloaded attachments?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Save_Attachments_Remove_Emails()

Const stPath As String = "c:\Attachments\"
Const EMBED_ATTACHMENT As Long = 1454
Const RICHTEXT As Long = 1

Dim noSession As Object
Dim noDatabase As Object
Dim noView As Object
Dim noDocument As Object
Dim noRemoveDocument As Object
Dim noNextDocument As Object

'Embedded objects are of the datatype Variant.
Dim vaItem As Variant
Dim vaAttachment As Variant

'Instantiate the Notes session.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")

'Instantiate the actual Notes database.
'(Here is the personal e-mail database used and since it's a
'local database no reference is made to any server.)
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("CAT-DH-23.apd.cat.com/Servers/Caterpillar", "mail\pamsmine.nsf")
' Please use this Open Function if the server is not referenced and GETDATABASE
' opens the db file if the file is in local system.
'Call noDatabase.Open("", "C:\notes\test.nsf")

'Folders are views in Lotus Notes and in this example the Inbox
'is used.
Set noView = noDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)")

'Get the first document in the defined view.
Set noDocument = noView.GetFirstDocument

'Iterate through all the e-mails in the view Inbox.
Do Until noDocument Is Nothing
Set noNextDocument = noView.GetNextDocument(noDocument)
'Check if the document has an attachment or not.
If noDocument.HasEmbedded Then
  Set vaItem = noDocument.GetFirstItem("Body")
  If vaItem.Type = RICHTEXT Then
    For Each vaAttachment In vaItem.EmbeddedObjects
     If vaAttachment.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
        'Save the attached file into the new folder.
        vaAttachment.ExtractFile stPath & vaAttachment.Name
        'Set the e-mail object which will be deleted.
        Set noRemoveDocument = noDocument
      End If
    Next vaAttachment
  End If
End If
Set noDocument = noNextDocument
'Delete the e-mails which have an attached file.
' If Not noRemoveDocument Is Nothing Then
 ' noRemoveDocument.Remove (True)
 ' Set noRemoveDocument = Nothing
'End If
Loop

'Release objects from memory.
Set noRemoveDocument = Nothing
Set noNextDocument = Nothing
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noView = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing

MsgBox "All the attachments in the Inbox have successfully been saved" & vbCrLf & _
     "and the associated e-mails have successfully been deleted.", vbInformation

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: How would you know if an attachment is already downloaded or not? There are no flags in a Notes mail database to specify if the attached document was downloaded. One way would be to test if the file exists already, but that would give errors for different files with the same name, attached to different e-mails. One other way would be to create a folder for each email that contains attachments.

Comment: Can't we mark the processed mail as read. And then only the unread mails will be processed. It's just an idea. Please suggest if this is possible? Also suggest how can we run this script 24/7.

Comment: And one more point @CST-Link , there will be no file with same name. Now please suggest how can I achieve that?

Comment: Added an answer, did it work for you?

Comment: @CST-Link Will check today and surely let you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the attachments are uniquely named, and the destination path contains only downloaded files, you may check easily if the attachment doesn't exist already (i.e. wasn't downloaded), using VBA's `Dir` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx (I never tested the VB.Net behavior, only VBA, but they seem pretty similar).

You may want to write:

```
' Previous code [...]
' If is an attachment ...
If vaAttachment.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
        ' ...check if was downloaded.
        If Dir(stPath & vaAttachment.Name) = "" Then
                'If not, save the attached file into the folder.
                vaAttachment.ExtractFile stPath & vaAttachment.Name

                'Set the e-mail object which will be deleted.
                Set noRemoveDocument = noDocument
        End If
End If
' Following code [...]
```

Comment: There is only one roadblock @CST-Link. If someone deletes the email from the folder, then it will download it again. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: @user3859736 well, the only thing I can think of is replacing the downloaded file with a zero-bytes file having the same name and the same extension, then changing the attribute to hidden so it won't show in folder (check `Dir` help also) But this requires a lot of manual "synchronization"... however, wouldn't be, for the purpose of archiving, better to let the files in the .nsf database, instead of downloading them periodically?

Comment: Okay, And can we provide a condition that only zipped attachments will be downloaded. (.zip format).

Comment: I am letting the files in the .nsf database , but as soon as i delete from C:\Attachments it downloads it again.

Comment: @user3859736 1) to download only zip files, test if the attachment name `vaAttachment.Name` ends in `".zip"` 2) You must keep somewhere the information about the downloaded files, so you don't download them again. The easy hacks are: keep all the files in your folder and check if they exist, or delete the attachments from e-mails. More sophisticated approach requires some effort (i.e. keeping track of the last e-mail with downloaded attachments, resuming every time from the previous last email, saving the "index" of actual last e-mail), sites like www.elance.com or www.odesk.com may help.

Comment: @user3859736  My question was meant in the lines of: why do you need to download the files from the .nsf? Why not open them directly from the .nsf (i.e. double-click on the file in your Lotus Notes client)?

Comment: I am coding a project in java where I am sending a mail to a mailbox configured in lotus notes. I couldn't do the downloading part in java so I thought to move to vbscript. After downloading the code will again process it for further requirements.

Comment: @user3859736 Oh, I see... well, sorry but for moment I can't help more than I did.